# Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting this error while I compile my code with `--aot`. without `--aot` it ignores this error.

here is the line on which I'm getting this error

```
<h2 class="inquiry-title" *ngIf="(summaryData.Title != undefined || summaryData.Title != null)">
    {{summaryData.Title}}
</h2>
```

Please suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that this code causes the error? Try removing `*ngIf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for some times got to know that when you compare one type with other with `AOT` it gives error because it compiles at the time of build.

So I changed variables type and it worked. I know its a mistake but you won't get idea until you compile code with `AOT` because at the development one generally don't serve with AOT.

ex:
    myVar1:number;
    myVar2:string;

and in component html if you want to compare it,

```
 *ngIf="myVar1 == myVar2"
 *ngIf="myVar1 == '0'"
```

it will give `Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string'`

Answer (score 5):

undefined and null are all falsy in javascript, you have just to do:

```
<h2 class="inquiry-title" *ngIf="summaryData.Title">
    {{summaryData.Title}}
</h2>
```

Comment: this will check for both `undefined` and `null`?

Comment: Yes, undefined, null, "", 0, ... are equivalent to false in javascript

Comment: Thank You, I'll try this

Comment: I've to be very careful as compiling with `--aot` takes more than 30mins. that's a pain

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya How big is your project?

Comment: @yurzui If I compile without `--aot` the size of `main.bundle` and `vendor.bundle` becomes `8.9mb` and `2.3 mb`  respectively

Comment: @yurzui It takes more than 30secs to load first page.

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya Have you tried to use lazy loading or reduce your templates?

Comment: @yurzui Other developers developed this and they come to me for optimization, they even didn't know about `--aot`. so if I compile with `--aot` there are countless errors.so, for compile with AOT I've to solve all the errors.

Comment: @yurzui how can I make sure they used `lazy loading`. I haven't used it yet

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya angular-cli shows you whethe they use lazy loading or not. You will see chunks for those modules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154507/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 0):

Used  declare your variable with any 
      like :-
       var actualVal:any = "";

Comment: Post this answer in comment section as it doesn't contain any code